# How can I reset the Secure Boot keys on my Surface Pro 4?

Tags: windows-10, uefi, secure-boot, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I have a Surface Pro 4 and I guess my secure boot keys got messed up somehow. On Surface Pro 3 this fix is as easy as going into the UEFI and resetting to the default keys, but there's no such option on the SP4 UEFI. I previously disabled secure boot to dual boot Arch. I've since deleted that partition. Every time I try to enable Secure Boot it returns "The system failed to update the Secure Boot certificate keyset." Does anyone have any clue on how I can go about resetting this? I have re-installed Windows and re-installed the SP4 firmware already. TPM is enabled as well.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need secure boot on? Why not just leave it off?

Comment: It slows down boot and there's an ugly red bar at the top of the screen. I really just want it back on because that's how it came.

Comment: Thomas - If you get a chance, look over my post here: https://superuser.com/questions/1104810/clearing-tpm-does-not-ask-for-new-password-but-change-owner-password-asks-for/1115768#1115768 and in particular look over the **PowerShell Resetting TPM** and **How to Clear the TPM Chip of any previous Ownership Credentials** sections for steps that may help you with this. It may be worth the read if nothing else at least for those two sections.

Comment: Thank you. I tried these steps and am still unable to enable secure boot.

Comment: Have you tried to [factory reset the Surface Pro 4](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/microsoft/microsoft-surface-pro-4/hardreset/first-method/)? I suggest to backup first your files.